# User mapping in OpenID Connect Relying Party

Tags: openid-connect

In this scenario my `Relying Party` (RP) not only wants to get information about a user but also needs to map a user to an internal user of the RP. Because of this I would like to map existing users of the `Identity Provider` (IdP) to users/groups in the RP. How can I achieve this with OpenID Connect (IdP and RP have a trust relationship; both are controlled by me)?

What are other options to solve this issue?

Comment: Are you using id token to authenticate the end user ?  Also if that's the case, the problem you have right now is the mismatch of sub parameter of id token with internal user ?

Comment: Also have you considered about directory synchronization ?

Comment: I don't know how to synchronize the directory (IDP to RP), that's the problem...

Comment: At the end I believe I would like to read all existing sub (subject identifier) of my IdP

Answer (score 3):

There are two approaches I see here; one from the OpenID Connect point of view, and the other from user directory handling.

**Id token claims**

OpenID Connect specification defines [standard claims in an id token](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#IDToken), and gives the freedom to define claims of our own. For example, if the `RP` cannot depend on `sub` claim to identify and map the end user, one can introduce a custom claim other than [standard claims](http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#StandardClaims) available.

> ID Tokens MAY contain other Claims. Any Claims used that are not understood MUST be ignored

For example, you can define a claim `rp_identifier`in id token which gives you the RP user id.

This will require some configuration to your IDP and also storing required identifier in IDP storage.

**Directory synchronization**

Not sure how your user directories are set up. But if you are using an external IDP, you may want to synchronize your internal and external user directories. I am not an expert in this domain, but for your reference [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/connect/active-directory-aadconnect) article explains about Azure active directory synchronization.

Although the user synchronization is out of scope of OpenID Connect, many who are moving to OpenID Connect at some point have to map internal users to users in IDP provide.

Comment: Id token claims: while I see the possibility I don't like to add anything special to the IDP (or its claims) just because of my RP. My RP could rely on the sub-claim but my RP needs to know up-front what subs to expect...

Directory synchronization: It's an internal IDP. The goal would be read out the directory from the IDP at the RP (RP already does something similar from an LDAP).

Comment: @Dunken What I proposed were ways you can map subs to other identifiers from your RP. As far as I know, OIDC doe not provide any other way to let your RP know what subs to expect. Validating id token and identifying end user is up to the RP. Why not think about changes on RP's user registry ?

Comment: Btw, since you are using LDAP, you may have a look on this - https://lsc-project.org/doku.php it is about LDAP user synchronization